# Random array or list size at scene start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I have an array of blocks. I want it to be with a random size/length when the scene starts.

```
 public GameObject[] blocks;
```

However if I try random range with an array I get all kinds of errors. Same with List<>.

I want my scene to start with a random number of items (within a range).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the type/message of the error?

Comment: Sure, you have to Instantiate GameObject's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the GameObjects

```
public int minRandomSize = 1;
public int maxRandomSize = 20;
public GameObject blockPrefab;

public void Start() {
    int size = Random.Range(minRandomSize,maxRandomSize+1);
    blocks = new GameObject[size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        blocks[i] = Instantiate(blockPrefab);

        // do stuff with blocks[i] to make that block different than the rest
    }
}
```